# Automatically naming applications in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I have a site structured like so:

```
Application.cfc
index.cfm
/Application1/index.cfm
/Application2/index.cfm
```

How can I set the application name in `Application.cfc` automatically based on the path, with a default name? So if the user is in `index.cfm`, I want the name to be `Default Application`, `/Application1/index.cfm` to have the name `Application1` and so on?

Comment: if the sub "applications" don't have their own application.cfc, aren't they *not* separate applications and therefore can't have their own name. You can certainly compute an application name within the .cfc when setting the name, but if you only have one application.cfc they'll all have the same name.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, but is there any reason to give each one a seperate application.cfc ? They're all using the same datasource, similar layouts, etc. The only reason I wanted to change the names is for better insight using FusionReactor.

Comment: You could probably use some form of inheritance to pass methods around so you don't have to duplicate them, but i haven't messed with that much WRT application.cfc's.

Comment: You say that you want better insight via FusionReactor. Is each directory really an independent site? You might want to look at slow pages and slow queries instead. Both of these are readily knowable.

Comment: Each directory is not technically independent. I just wanted to sort of "pretend" it was to take advantage of the App filter on the Transaction pages.

Comment: They will have separate `application` scopes, are you okay with that?

Comment: @AlexBaban I'd have to think through, but I think it's a simple enough website that it won't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work but I am not 100% sure. You can try to extend the application.cfc. Ben Nadel has written a blog about this here https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2115-extending-the-application-cfc-coldfusion-framework-component-with-a-relative-path-proxy.htm .

Below a simplified example:

Application.cfc (root folder)

```
<cfcomponent output="false">
    <cfset this.name = "Parent" />
    <cfset this.applicationTimeout = createTimeSpan( 0, 0, 10, 0 ) />
    <cffunction name="dummy" access="public" returntype="void" output="true" hint="test">
        <cfreturn />
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="onApplicationStart" access="public" returntype="boolean" output="false" hint="I initialize the application.">
        <cfreturn true />
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="onRequestStart" access="public" returntype="boolean" output="false" hint="I initialize the request.">
        <cfreturn true />
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="onRequest" access="public" returntype="void" output="true" hint="I process the user's request.">
        <cfargument name="script" type="string" required="true" hint="I am the request script." />

        <cfdump var="#this#" label="THIS"/>
        <br />
        <hr />
        <br />
        <cfinclude template="#arguments.script#" />
        <cfreturn />
     </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

rootApplication.cfc (child folder)

```
<cfinclude template="../Application.cfc" />
```

Application.cfc (child folder)

```
<cfcomponent extends="RootApplication">
    <cfset this.name = "child" />
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: This worked really well, and I can easily put it into a folder whose files I want to isolate in FusionReactor, and take them out later on.